# Show continuity and holomorphism for a function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

> Let $A = \left\{ z \in D_r \big| \; Im(z) \geq 0 \right\}, f : A \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{C}$ continuos on $A$, holomorphic on the inner of $A$ and
>   real-valued for $\left]-r,r\right[$. Let further be $F(z) :=
>  \begin{cases}f(z) & z \in A \\ \overline{f(\bar{z})} & \bar{z} \in
>  A\end{cases}$
>
> Show that $F(z)$ is continuos on $D_r(0)$ and that $F$ is holomorphic on $D_r(0)$.
>
> ($D$ is the region of convergence).

I do understand convergence in matters of sequences, but don't understand what should be shown in this context. Can you please explain to me how that $A$ looks like and what is needed to be done to show the continuity of $F$ on $D_r(0)$?

Comment: That's not meant to a fraction I take it in the definition of F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read of a thing called Schwarz reflection principle from Stein/Shakarchi's book. I believe it should answer your question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This helps me to show that F is holomorphic on some subset, but how can I show it is holomorphic on $D_r(0)$ (or does this immediately follow)? Does it help me to show the continuity as well?